# Drag and drop images on div

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to be able to append the images to the `ul` inside the dropzone `div`.I want to have all the images appear horizontally, but so far when I drag images from desktop to the red square nothing happens.

This is something I extracted from the internet. Any help is appreciated.

```
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');

    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    });


    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.dataTransfer.files; 

        for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++) {
            if (file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e2) {
            // finished reading file data.
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src= e2.target.result;
            node.append(img);
            document.getElementById('image_bar').appendChild(node);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file); .
    }
}
});
```

```
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <div><ul id="image_bar"></ul></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First u need to remove the . on the line `reader.readAsDataURL(file); .` then when you run the code, you will see in the Console (F12 in chrome) that "node is not defined"

this code works:

create a file named myfile.html with this content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hi</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <div><ul id="image_bar"></ul></div>
</div>
  <script>
var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');    
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        });


        dropZone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var files = e.dataTransfer.files; 

            for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++) {
                if (file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e2) {
                // finished reading file data.
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src= e2.target.result;
                document.getElementById('image_bar').appendChild(img);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    }); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working? What should happen and what is happening

Comment: when you drag a image in to a browser , the whole image sort of opens up. And thats what happens .My actual code is not working . It works in the code pen . So maybe I have put the javascript code at the wrong place .Currently its under <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Please read the comments in  the code

```js
var url = "";


dropZone.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = data.files;

  handleFiles(files);
}


//a function to handle the dragged files
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    //a regEx to check if the dragged file is an image
    var isImagen = /^image\//;
    //if it's not an image
    if (!isImagen.test(file.type)) {
      continue;
    }
    //but if it's an image
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    img.onload = function() {   
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height;
    //append the image to the image_bar
    image_bar.appendChild(img);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);  
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="dropZone" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
  <div><ul id="image_bar"></ul></div>
</div>
```